# Should jar files be compressed for desktop applications?

Tags: java, jar, compression

Just wondering, if it is generally a good idea to compress jar files that will be shipped with a desktop application (no network access to jars), of if the decompression will have a bigger impact than file io.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers so far, and sorry for being a bit unclear here. I was not speaking about shipping the jars to the customer, but of the optimal format for the jar files on the disk when the app start ups. I know that jar files are zip files and can be served with different compression levels (or no compression at all), and I was directly wondering how compression would alter startup performance, not only on my dev box (has a fast SSD disk in it, but also on slower disks).

Comment: The internal format of a java jar is a ZIP archive.  Either set of tools can be used with either file type.  The files may be compressed (faster disk access) or uncompressed (less cpu).  Leave them as you get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that the answer depends on your application.  However, it should be easy to determine experimentally if compressed JARs give faster or slower startup for your application.  Just build your application JAR file with compression on and compression off, and compare the application startup times.  (Try it on different machines; e.g. with slow discs, fast discs, SSD, and with different amounts of RAM.  Bear in mind that some OSes cache files aggressively, and take this into account in your timing measurements.)

While you are at it, you should also investigate the impact of different compression levels (via the `jar` command options) and using [`pack200`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/pack200.html)

---

Having said that, my gut feeling is that the difference between compressed and uncompressed for locally installed JARs will be small enough that the user will hardly notice the difference.

Answer (score 2):

In almost any reasonable desktop situation, the cost of disk IO is way higher than the cost of compression.  It'll almost certainly be a win to compress files.

That said, a JAR file is already compressed.  Doubly compressing things is generally not worth the effort.  So I'd say no, don't compress your JAR files as they are already compressed.

Comment: I suspect the OP's question had more to do whether they should compress *their* JARs before delivery - not compress files someone else has given them.  JAR files don't have to be compressed - it's just a zip file, and it's quite legit to not compress the contents.

Comment: *"In almost any reasonable desktop situation, the cost of disk IO is way higher than the cost of compression. It'll almost certainly be a win to compress files."* - I'm not sure that is true.  On a Linux box with plenty of memory, files will be cached in memory by the OS.  Read speed could (in theory) approach the speed of a memory-to-memory copy.

Comment: I don't believe the files are cached at the beginning, but the files data blocks will be in the cache when the app has loaded a few classes. At least the blocks covered with the class files.

Comment: @Daniel - on a Linux box, if you used the archive file recently, there is a *good chance* that it will all be in the buffer cache *from the beginning*.  (That's one reason why I prefer Linux over Windows for s/w development.)

Comment: Okey, but our customers usually don't develop, and they tend to run windows.

Comment: @Stephen C: If your box is so awesome that it can hold random JAR files in memory just in case they are used (honestly, any reasonable computer from the last few years), I'd be surprised if you could even notice the difference in timing between compressed and uncompressed.  According to a random benchmarking site I found, an early 2005 Athlon could do 60MB/s decompress.  Probably is irrelevant either way :)

Comment: @Steven - you are probably right about it being irrelevant either way.  But if the OP cares enough to ask, he should test it.

Comment: Sure.  I just think it'll be below the threshold of measurement, or at least caring.  While if you have to read a lot from e.g. the network (say you're using web start or nfs) the size on disk could matter a lot.  Either way I agree - you'll have to test it and the answer will be very situational.